# Is there a regular expression equivalent for python's glob module?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, glob, python-module

Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module matches all files and directories that match a glob expression. It is internally implemented by using `os.listdir()` and `fnmatch.fnmatch()`, according to the documentation.

Is there an out-of-the-box module or function which matches regular expressions instead of using globs?

Comment: Sure, python re moudle.

Comment: That's partially right, but you would have to construct a pathname list with `os.walk` (warning: it doesn't returns the list) and then `re.match` on every item

Comment: @KaeptmBlaubaer  I somehow missed the os.walk() method. os.walk() with the re.match will certainly do what I want to do, though it may be inefficient, as all files and subdirectories will be traversed, irrespective of match, instead of restricting to just the subdirectories that partially match the regex. I expect that this was the reason why glob uses os.listdir() instead of using os.walk().

Answer (score 2):

Not a module, but there's a script available that does file renaming using regular expressions, [here.](https://bitbucket.org/ambv/rename/src/f2fb301156220cc8ba0a7c049012d0a92a97a292/src/rename.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Obviously, this has code to do matching based on the regex. You might contact the author to see about getting a match-only interface to the code, or maybe just hack it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this almost works. I wanted tested code for scanning directories, and doing partial (prefix) match against subdirectories. Kaeptm Blaubaer's method using os.walk() and re.match() will work too, but is likely to inefficient.